# How to assign a value to a property of an object only if that object is not null in c#

Tags: c#

```
Homework homework = isposted ? new Homework() : null;
If(homework != null) 
{
 homework.Id = 3;
 homework.Name = "Draw an Apple";
}

// Why can't I use like this ?
homework ? .Id = 3;
homework ? .Name = "Draw an Apple"; // instead of checking for if condition
```

// Is there any way to minimise the code length?`

Answer (score 5):

you can use object initialization to shorten it a fair bit

```
Homework homework = isposted 
? new Homework
{
    Id = 3,
    Name = "Draw an Apple"
} : null;
```

> Actually, I had an object like Homework homework = isposted ? oldHomework : null;

I would assume you want a copy of the `oldHomework`, then you can use this code below

```
Homework homework = isposted 
? new Homework
{
    Id = oldHomework.Id,
    Name = oldHomework.Name
} : null;
```

Comment: Actually, I had an object like `Homework homework = isposted ? oldHomework : null;`

Answer (score 2):

You can't assign a value to an object that is NULL.  The `?` is for *reading* properties, not setting them.

```
var x = homework.Id;   // Will throw an error if homework is NULL
var y = homework?.Id;  // Will be NULL if homework is NULL
```

For setting properties, you definitely want to check for NULL and then only set them if it is not NULL.  Just exactly the way you're doing it is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such operator, the closest way of achieving what you wanted I could think of is by using an extension method like this:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void IfNotNull<T>(this T obj, Action<T> action)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return;
        action(obj);
    }
}

Homework homework = isposted ? new Homework() : null;
homework.IfNotNull(h => h.Id = 3);
homework.IfNotNull(h => h.Name = "Draw an Apple");
```

However the extension method still uses an `if` statement. It doesn't need to be an extension method.

> To be honest **I'd never use such solution** in a real project. You should not sacrifice code readability just to use fewer lines of code, this solution doesn't even improve performance. I only wanted to share the closest solution I could find for your question.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge there exists no simple syntax element to do this, but if you want a one-liner, avoiding the  `if`, you can use reflections:

```
(homework as Homework)?
.GetType()
.GetProperty(nameof(Homework.Id))?
.SetMethod?
.Invoke(homework, new object[] {3});
```